# R data frame: add values in common rows

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a data frame like this .

```
> df1
  portfolio       date ticker quantity price
1      port 2010-01-01   AAPL      100    10
2      port 2010-01-01   AAPL      200    10
3      port 2010-01-01   AAPL      400    11
```

If the rows of `df1` except `quantity` are same, then add the `quantity` of common rows.
I mean, i need the following output

```
portfolio       date ticker quantity price
1      port 2010-01-01   AAPL      300    10
3      port 2010-01-01   AAPL      400    11
```

How can i do that? Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `aggregate`. Assuming your `data.frame` is called "mydf":

```
> aggregate(quantity ~ ., mydf, sum)
  portfolio       date ticker price quantity
1      port 2010-01-01   AAPL    10      300
2      port 2010-01-01   AAPL    11      400
```

---

Of course, we should all now wait for the `data.table` and `ddply` versions to populate the answers list....

Answer (score 5):

Here you go... :-)

For `plyr` :

```
ddply(df, .(portfolio, date, ticker, price),summarize, quantity=sum(quantity))
```

For `data.table` :

```
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[,list(quantity=sum(quantity)),by=list(portfolio,date,ticker,price)]
```

There may be a more concise way to express the list of grouping variables. Otherwise, the `aggregate` solution is much more elegant.

Comment: Sure--just store all the other variable names in a new vector after using `setdiff`: `x <- setdiff(names(df), "quantity"); ddply(df, x, summarize, quantity = sum(quantity)); dt[, list(quantity = sum(quantity)), by = x]`.

Comment: And, +1 for obliging me :)

Comment: @AnandaMahto Thanks for the +1, but my answer should not have more upvotes than yours... :-)